# How to perform an action after the last draggable element has been dropped..

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

After the last drop-action (the droppable element number is always different) I want to show e.g. a submit button.

That is a working example (corresponding part):

```
$('.unsortedChoiceBox1 li').draggable({
    appendTo: "body",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: true,
    scope: "d1",
});

$( "#droppable1 ol" ).droppable({
    scope: "d1",
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    accept: '.unsortedChoiceBox1 li',
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.draggable.draggable('option','revert',false); 
        ui.draggable.clone().appendTo(this);
        ui.draggable.remove();

    }
});
```

Please give me an idea: How can I detect, which draggable element is the last one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is code. you need to count drag element and increament counter on drop event

```
    $('.unsortedChoiceBox1 li').draggable({
                appendTo: "body",
                helper: "clone",
                revert: true,
                scope: "d1",
            });
            var count = 0;
var drags = $('.unsortedChoiceBox1 li').size();
            $("#droppable1 ol").droppable({
                scope: "d1",
                activeClass: "ui-state-default",
                hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
                accept: '.unsortedChoiceBox1 li',
                drop: function(event, ui) {
                    ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', false);
                    ui.draggable.clone().appendTo(this);
                    ui.draggable.remove();
                    count++;
                    if (drags == count) {
                        alert('all elements are dropped');
                        //show submit button
                    }

                }
            });
```

Comment: thank you very much, I am testing now.. Does not work, because: a draggable element has already been deleted after the corresponding drop. Therefore you will not able to detect the size. I think, I have to work with 2 counters?

Comment: Maybe I have to save the size before all the operations in a variable. That could be the solution, thank you..